# All window need to close while user session expire How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, session-storage

I am trying to close window with session storage, its not working y ??

For me I open new window in different && different modules, so I cant maintain the "Var" for that I use session storage Globally for my application

```html
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>
var my1;


function openWin() {
my1 = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
alert(my1)
sessionStorage.setItem('aa',my1);

}

function closeWin() {
var retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem('aa');
retrievedObject.close();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Session storage holds strings, there is no way to store the reference to a window...

Comment: but when I put log its returning window object how @ epascarello

Answer (score 0):

I created a working version in plunker for you [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/N4s5PINcXh1TbhfHKpGI?p=preview).

However you need to consider the points that if your code is running inside a tab and that gets closed, then your code will never run to close other windows and the user has to close them all.

BTW: your code won't work inside `stackoverflow` since it is `sandboxed`. (you don't have access to session storage inside it)

Update:

Because that my1 is a reference to an instance of the window, when you put it in sessionStorage, it will loose the references. So the only thing that comes to my mind is to store it locally. Look at the updated plunker.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Because you are storing an instance of window object it somehow looses the references. Look at the update @epascarello

Comment: @Yaser I Know that , but in my case i need to close all the new window , so how can I , With out global variable I cant do anything

Comment: You can add them as an array and loop through it for closing all

Comment: How to keep an Global array for my whole application,because i will open new tab in different && different application

Comment: If it is nee tab you won't have access to them so you cannot close them from one tab, the only thing that you can do is to inject a function into each tab and upon expiry self close them

Comment: In previous code (Session Storage) , while close button perform i am getting window object but I am unable to close the window .. It showing like function not found

Comment: Yes because it will loose the functions when it gets saved, only properties will get saved

Comment: k then how to maintain the window object globally

Comment: If it is single page mean, code work correctly,when it comes to all tab means it will not

Comment: Global only has meaning inside current window and its children, not separate windows